# Getting Nullpointer exception while creating a hibernate mapping XML file?

Tags: hibernate-mapping, eclipse-mars, jboss-tools, nhibernate-configuration

I'm trying to create a XML based configuration for a model class. Using Hibernate XML Mapping file option from hibernate menu which comes with the JBoss Tools.
But it throws *NullPointerException* as in the image shown below.

Using:

```
Java 8 and Eclipse Mars 4.5.2
```

```
JBoss Tools 4.3.1.Final
```

[image]

Please suggest me a solution to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

//Elusive Log
[image]

Comment: Well have you looked at the error log for more details like the dialog says? What does it say?

Comment: It shows the same text, I've updated the above snip.

Comment: The log should show a stack trace telling us where the exception is occurring - show us that.

Comment: @greg-449 I hope this is the log you're talking about (//Elusive Log added above). If not please tell me the location from where i can get the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a JBoss bug - see the bug report [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-21766?_sscc=t).

The report says the bug is fixed in JBoss 4.4.2.AM1

Comment: But I'm using Hibernate v5.2.x. Then that means this issue should not appear.

Comment: Sorry, misread the bug report - the error is in JBoss when using Hibernate. JBoss 4.4.2.AM1 contains the fix

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - Now I've to update my eclipse from mars to neon 4.6.1 to support JBoss 4.4.2.AM1. I'll comment my result after trying this combo. Thanks

Comment: Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 and JBoss Tools 4.4.2 combination works. Thanks Again.